# Creating asset folder using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to create an asset folder using

```py
ee.data.createFolder()
```

But I get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'ee.data' has no attribute 'createFolder'

How do I create a folder using the python api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `ee.data.createAsset()` method, like so:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
ee.data.createAsset({'type': 'ImageCollection'}, 'users/[your-username]/test-folder')
```

Note that the type is different whether you're using the Cloud API or not. From the docs:

> **Creates an asset from a JSON value.**
>
> To create an empty image collection or folder, pass in a "value"
>   object   with a "type" key whose value is "ImageCollection" or
>   "Folder".   If you are using the Cloud API, use "IMAGE_COLLECTION" or
>   "FOLDER".
>
> Args:
>       value: An object describing the asset to create or a JSON string
>           with the already-serialized value for the new asset.
>       opt_path: An optional desired ID, including full path.
>       opt_properties: The keys and values of the properties to set
>           on the created asset.
>
> Returns:
>       A description of the saved asset, including a generated ID.

Comment: I just want to comment that the documentation is extremely misleading as https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-createfolder is referenced.